# Spark Streaming - Issue with Passing parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Please take a look at the following spark streaming code written in scala:

```
object HBase {
  var hbaseTable = ""
  val hConf = new HBaseConfiguration()
  hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "zookeeperhost")

  def init(input: (String)) {
    hbaseTable = input
  }
  def display() {
    print(hbaseTable)
  }
  def insertHbase(row: (String)) {
    val hTable = new HTable(hConf,hbaseTable)
  }
}

object mainHbase {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 5) {
      System.err.println("Usage: MetricAggregatorHBase <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads> <hbaseTable>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads, hbaseTable) = args
    HBase.init(hbaseTable)
    HBase.display()
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("mainHbase")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))
    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
    val topicpMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicpMap).map(_._2)
    val storeStg = lines.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreach(HBase.insertHbase))
    lines.print()
    ssc.start()
  }
}
```

I am trying to initialize the parameter `hbaseTable` in the object `HBase` by calling `HBase.init` method. It was setting the parameter properly. I confirmed that by calling the `HBase.display` method in the next line.

However when `HBase.insertHbase` method in the `foreachRDD` is called, its throwing error that `hbaseTable` is not set.

Update with exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Table qualifier must not be empty
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.isLegalTableQualifierName(TableName.java:179)
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.isLegalTableQualifierName(TableName.java:149)
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.<init>(TableName.java:303)
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.createTableNameIfNecessary(TableName.java:339)
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf(TableName.java:426)
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:156)
```

Can you please let me know how to make this code work.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact exception that is thrown.

Comment: @lambdas updated with the exception thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Where is this code running" - that's the question that we need to ask in order to understand what's going on.

`HBase` is a Scala object - by definition it's a singleton construct that  gets initialized with 'only once' semantics in the JVM.

At the initialization point, `HBase.init(hbaseTable)` is executed in the driver of this Spark application, initializing this object with the given value in the VM of the driver.

But when we do: `rdd.foreach(HBase.insertHbase)`, the closure is executed as a task on each executor that hosts a partition for the given RDD.  At that point, the object `HBase`  is initialized on each VM for each executor. As we can see, no initialization has happened on this object at that point.

There're two options:

We can add some checking "isInitialized" to the `HBase` object and add the -now conditional- call to initialize on each call to `foreach`.
Another option would be to use

```
rdd.foreachPartitition{partition => 
     HBase.initialize(...)
     partition.foreach(elem => HBase.insert(elem))
}
```

This construction will amortize any initialization by the amount of element in each partition. It's also possible to combine it with an initialization check to prevent unnecessary bootstrap work.